# OneDrive has suddenly stopped syncing "live" data

Tags: microsoft-excel, sync, onedrive

Seemingly randomly my OneDrive has stopped syncing my files while they are open or syncing at all for that matter. I am working on an excel sheet with another person and when I used to open it from my OneDrive folder in windows explorer it would open with the "autosave" function enabled and I would be able to see the other person in the file if they were there at the same time as me. Now for some reason when I open any file it will open with "autosave" off and will not sync when I make changes or exit the file. I have tried resetting OneDrive and reinstalling but neither has helped. I have gotten sync errors as well but when I open the file to merge changes there are no changes to merge or any dialog mentioning fixing sync issues. I'm not sure where to go from here.

If I go to OneDrive in a browser and try to choose "Open in app" the wring Microsoft app will open. E.g. when I try to open a file in excel it will try to open it in word.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall Office to fix your Office file extension issues?

Comment: I am running a repair on Office right now to see if that helps. I suspect thats not the root of the issues though. I was able to open a "live" version of an excel file in excel from the "recommended for you" section. It seems like the onedrive folder files just dont want to open in "live" mode.

Answer (score 0):

any updates on this?
I've the same problem with one drive business and excel 2019. Already did a repair on office 2019, reinstalled one drive but the problem persists.
I've spoked with microsoft and they said office 2019 doesn't support imediate syncing ( only office 365) but it was working fine till yesterday. I' tested with office 2021 and it is working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sadly no updates on this. I have been speaking with IT support at my company as well and they cannot figure out why this link has stopped functioning. I will try to update here if I can get this solved

Answer (score 0):

File - Options - Trust center - Privacy options - Privacy configuration - enable everything

Comment: Please explain why this works.  Short answers get deleted by the bot.